# Python - Kivy Automatic Focus adn Virtual Keyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Goo day all,
I have the following codes I'd like that on the text box I don't need to go there with mouse but to find the cursor already there, more once I need to write into the box I would like to have a virtual keyboard.

Thanks for your support

My codes :

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivy.lang import Builder

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

import requests

import re

from kivy.config import Config



KV = """


"""


class Metar2App(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.title = "Metar Query"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        return Builder.load_file("metar3KV.kv")


    def takeicao(self):
                        if self.root.ids["mdtext"].text:                                             
                            icao = self.root.ids["mdtext"].text.upper()
                            self.root.ids["mdlab"].text = "Loading Please ..."                                                  
                            address = requests.get('https://xxxx/api/data/xxxxx'+'&taf=true')                            
                            self.root.ids["mdlab"].text = f"\n{(address.text)}"
                            print (self.root.ids["mdlab"].text)
                            self.text_input.focus = True
                            #print (address.text)
                        else :
                            self.root.ids["mdlab"].text = "PLEASE WRITE THE ICAO CODE"
                            #print (text_response)
                            #Label = (text_response)


   

Metar2App().run()
```